# Error using postman calling Bulk API 2.0 to upload file

Tags: bulk-api-v2

I am following the salesforce offical guide on Bulk2.0. I am able to create a job but when I try to upload a csv file, it shows the error. here is the call. however, I can use workbench to upload the same csv file. please see the screenshots below. I wonder what i have done wrong with Postman[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out why, when I copied the endpoint URL from web page to post man, the blank symbols at the end of the url also got pasted into postman, thus postman sents the URL with blank symbols, and salesforce doesn't recognize the end point.
The solution: simply check the end of the URL and make sure there is no blank symbols like CRLF